# Google Maps API InfoWindow & getJSON

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

For 1 of our assignments we had to use the Google Maps API to create a web-app where we would display news articles by location

[An example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8quGy.png)

I'm working on a javascript of the code, specifically addMarker where I would add a marker to the map and also display the info window when this marker is clicked.

The relevant part of my code is as follows:

```
function addMarker(place)
{

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: place.latitude, lng: place.longitude},
    // {lat: 42.377, lng: -71.1256},
    map: map,
    label: place.place_name + ", " + place.admin_name1,
    icon: {
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(11, 50),
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(22, 40),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 40),
      }
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function(){

  var content = "<ul>";

  // pull articles
  var parameters = {geo: place.postal_code}

  $.getJSON("articles.php", parameters)
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    for (var i=0; i < articles.length; i++)
    {
        content +='<li> + articles[i].title + </li>';
    }
    content += '</ul>';

    showInfo(marker, content);

  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // log error to browser's console
    console.log(errorThrown.toString());
  });

  });

}
```

which generates the markers alright, but for the life of my I can't figure out why it doesn't show the infoWindow when I click on it.

Appreciate any help I might be able to get, thank you all so much

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an info window in your code, nor are you trying to open one. This is basically what you need to display a map, marker and an info window. Just need to customise it to your liking. Note `var infowindow`, and also the `marker.addListener` to `infowindow.open` which trigger the infowindow to display.

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

var contentString = '<div id="content">';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

This code and more info can be found at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows